# Printing even numbers with commas except the last in C# not working

Tags: c#, arrays, iteration

I have been trying to fix this issue for some days now but can't find the error. It seems as simple as an if statement for the code to print commas for all but the last number. It worked for me putting random numbers but when i put the specific numbers (24,7,35,2,27,7,89)it prints the comma at the end.

[Print even numbers with commas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMdgs.png)

This is my code, but i tried multiple other ways.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Transactions;

namespace ArrayExercises
{
    class TaskFour
    {
        public static void FindEvenNumbers()
        {
            int[] input = new int[7];
            int count = 1;
            string comma = ",";
            Console.WriteLine("[== Please Enter 7 numbers ==]");
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
              Console.WriteLine($"Enter number {count}:");
              input[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());              
              count++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The even numbers in this array are: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
              
                if (input[i] % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    if (i < input.Length)
                    {
                        Console.Write(input[i] + comma);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(input[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Why not just `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", input.Where(x => x % 2 ==0).Select(x => x.ToString()))`

Comment: I am assuming that this is some sort of exercise, tutorial, and throwing lambdas around might not help with the learning.

Comment: `if (i < input.Length)` -> `if (i < input.Length-1)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @zaitsman. The reason is, this is for an exercise and supposed to do it only with what we have learned so far without using methods. It has to be arrays and loops

Comment: @zaitsman The name of the class is `TaskFour` so I'm guessing that this means this must be done with loops.

Comment: Don't think "I print a ',' _after_ each number, but the last" - think "I print a ',' _before_ each number, but the first". Also, instead of having separate `count` just  do `{(i+1)}`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `StringBuilder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code without introducing any extra space using `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (input[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        if (i != 0) Console.Write(comma);
        Console.Write(input[i]);
        
    }
}
```

Or use the inbuilt `string.Join` function.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', input.Where(i => i % 2 == 0)));
```

Comment: `"It has to be arrays and loops"`... and yes, the OP put this in the comment section, not your fault.

Comment: `if(i < input.Length-1) Console.Write(comma);` This only works if the last even number in the array is at the last index.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys, still none of that worked for me. it keeps giving me that comma at the end

Comment: @Fildor I haven't seen the input. Updated the logic

Comment: @Otto Please see the updated result. It is working perfectly

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Yes you are correct the logic was not consistent. But updated the logic and working perfectly

Comment: @VimalCK Thanks a million mate. it is working now for me. I think my IDE was not saving properly.

Answer (score 1):

***This answer assumes that the above is homework/tutorial, there are more efficient means that what I am posting here***

The problem is this segment:

```
                if (i < input.Length)
                {
                    Console.Write(input[i] + comma);
                }
```

The *problem* is that you are always outputting a comma, regardless of what is to follow. I think that the easiest approach would be to add the comma before hand, meaning, while you are going through the second loop, if you have already printed a number before, you pre-pend a comma and print the number you have, if you did not print any numbers before (that is, you are about to print the first number) then you do not prepend the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Your else condition will never execute. If you are rookie in C# then I would suggest get all even numbers first and store it in the list. Iterate over again to print with comma and just skip the last comma.

```
//Your existing source code
List<int> evenNumber = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
   if (input[i] % 2 == 0) 
   {
       evenNumber.Add(input[i]);
   }
}
for(int i = 0; i < evenNumber.Length; i++)
{
   //Print just number if it is last, otherwise print number with comma
   if(i == evenNumber.Length - 1)
        Console.Write(evenNumber[i]);
   else
        Console.Write(evenNumber[i]+comma);
}
```

---

If you know [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) then use linq to get list of even numbers and print list of even numbers with ',' as a delimiter

```
var evenNumbers = input.Where(x => x % 2 ==0);  //Filter all even numbers
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", evenNumbers);  //Print using string.Join
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` will always be less than the length the input due to the loop's condition.

Instead of implementing this yourself, you could let `string.join` do the heavy lifting for you:

```
string result = string.Join(comma, input.Where(i => i % 2 == 0));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: `"It has to be arrays and loops"`... and yes, the OP put this in the comment section, not your fault.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version:

```
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (input[i] % 2 == 0) 
    {
        result += $",{input[i]}";
    }
}
Console.WriteLine( result.Length > 0 ? result.Substring(1).ToString() : "");
```